# Setting StackoverFlows searchbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Executing this code `$("input[name=q]").value = "Hello";` should enter "Hello" into the stackoverflow searchbox. However it remains empty. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$("input[name=q]")` returns a jquery object, not a raw DOM element. You'll need to grab the actual element first, by doing `$("input[name=q]").get(0).value = "Hello";`

Or use the jquery method and do `$("input[name=q]").val("Hello");`

Answer (score 3):

Because it should be:

```
$("input[name=q]").val("Hello");
```

Bit of an odd question, do you mind me asking why? :)

Comment: just playing around with chrome extensions, so SO is my victim for today ;)

Comment: Ha, fair enough! :)